# How to set enum Type indexer in Spring.NET configuration xml?

Tags: arrays, enums, spring.net, indexer

I have this code:

```
public enum StateId { NotSet = 0, AL, ..., WY }

public class EnumBasedArray<I,V>:IEnumerable<V> 
{
  public V this[I index]
  { 
    get { return _data[index]; }
    set { _data[index] = value; }
  }
  // other code to manage values internally
}

public class AnotherObject { ... }

public class ArrayOfAnotherObjectByStateId:EnumBasedArray<StateId, AnotherObject> {}
```

Where I have trouble is telling Spring.NET the values of each item in the StateId-indexed array via the configuration XML file.

In code, I'd write something like:

```
var x = new ArrayOfAnotherObjectByStateId();
x[StateId.AZ] = new AnotherObject(...);
x[StateId.CA] = new AnotherObject(...);
```

How do I do this in the Spring xml?
The closest I've come is:

```
<object id="matrix" type="ArrayOfAnotherObjectByStateId">
   <property name="[AZ]" ref="AZ.Matrix">
</object>

<object id="AZ.Matrix" type="AnotherObject" />
```

which gives me the error
"Error creating context 'spring.root': 'AZ' node cannot be resolved for the specified context"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<object id="matrix" type="ArrayOfAnotherObjectByStateId">
   <property name="[T(NamespaceYouUse.StateId).AZ]" ref="AZ.Matrix">
</object>
```

Tested with Spring.NET 1.2

Comment: Thank you-worked like a charm!  Much (much) cleaner than the factory workaround with a slew of objects created solely to make Spring happy.  Thank you!